# Can't resolve merge conflict in TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit, merge-conflict-resolution

I must be missing something obvious but I don't seem to be able to resolve a merge conflict in TortoiseGit. At least not resolve it in any way other than keeping the current version.

During a merge a message pops up saying there are conflicts. If I open the resolve GUI there are a list of files that have merge conflicts. Right clicking on a file gives a context menu that includes Edit Conflicts. Selecting this I have kdiff3 set as the merge tool which opens with the file.BASE, file.LOCAL and file.REMOTE files. I make the edits and save the file. The directory now contains the edited file marked with a conflict, the three files that were opened as A, B and C in kdiff3 and a file with the descriptor of the original and an extension .orig. If I now mark the file as resolved, either through the resolve GUI or the context menu, the three files dissappear and the file that was 'resolved' reverts to the file.LOCAL version. I expected that resolving a file I'd edited to resolve the merge conflicts would keep that file rather than the .LOCAL file.

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression in TortoiseGit 2.15.0 (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/4086)

It is already fixed in the preview releases: https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/

Comment: Thanks. I had searched the TortoiseGit issues - obviously not well enough. I wasted a lot of time trying to get this to work. It was the first time I had used TortoiseGit to resolve merge conflicts and I couldn't understand why there was nothing on the 'net referencing this problem with, what I imagine, is a fairly common procedure. This explains why.